# WordPress Simple Translation

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, translation, gettext

I am quite new to WordPress theme development, I've been exploring some starter themes and trying to study how they develop their themes. I've learned how they translate the words or phrase by using `__()` function and `_e()` function, but I never saw some dynamic functions being translated using the `__()` and `_e()` functions (e.g. `the_excerpt()`, `the_title()`)

So my question is, is it okay to translate dynamic WordPress values using the `__()` and `_e()` functions? Particularly this code:

`_e(the_title(), 'domain');`

or, WordPress automatically translates the returned value, and it is not necessary to use those translator functions?

Answer (score 1):

To translate dynamic values you have to use the `__()` as you could run into issues if you don't. Here's some really nice information I read when I translated my first wordpress site, and it came out great.

You should know that these calls are called `getText` wrappers... `getText` is software found in most servers and you can find more info about it in their website:

### [getText Project](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/)

Another awesome article on how to use these can be found in the I can localize website found here:

### [How to localize wordpress themes](http://blog-en.icanlocalize.com/installing-wordpress-for-multiple-language-blogs/how-to-localize-wordpress-themes-and-plugins-with-gettext/)

As usual your primary source for this should be the wordpress codex, while its not mega complete is the stem of this idea specific to a wordpress install.

### [WordPress Codex on Translating](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress)

Finally, here is a nice couple of tools that will help with the translation. This helps find your `getText` calls from any PHP file (hint, you can upload a zip and it will generate a file that you can then use with [Poedit](http://www.poedit.net/).

### [ICanLocalize PHP Scanner](http://www.icanlocalize.com/tools/php_scanner)